# how to count days without weekends between 2 dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

the question is: how to count time between start and finish of process without weekends (in hours)?
I have 2 tabls
first one:

| deal_id | status_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12.05.2021 12:37 |
| 1 | 2 | 25.05.2021 14:23 |

second one:

| dt | type |
| --- | --- |
| 12.05.2021 | work |
| ... | hol/work |
| 25.05.2021 | work |

"hol" means weekends

I did that:

```
select distinct(deal_id),
    round(extract (epoch from(max(created_at) over (partition by deal_id)- 
                  min(created_at) over (partition by deal_id)))/3600, 0) 
        as time_for_deal
from table_1
```

But I don't know how to count and subtract weekends
Please help

Comment: Note that `distinct` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `select distinct` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `select distinct deal_id, ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of postgresql's built in date functions to find out and exclude weekends, e.g

```sql
WITH valid_dates AS (
    SELECT
        deal_id,
        created_at::date AS date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'work' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY deal_id ORDER BY created_at) AS work_days
    FROM
        table_1
),
time_intervals AS (
    SELECT
        t1.deal_id,
        t1.date AS start_date,
        LEAD(t1.date) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.deal_id ORDER BY t1.date) AS end_date,
        t1.work_days AS start_work_days,
        LEAD(t1.work_days) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.deal_id ORDER BY t1.date) AS end_work_days
    FROM
        valid_dates t1
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM valid_dates t2
            WHERE t2.deal_id = t1.deal_id AND t2.date = t1.date
        )
)
SELECT
    t.deal_id,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM generate_series(t.start_date, t.end_date - interval '1 day', '1 day')) IN (6, 7)
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    ) * 24 AS time_for_deal_in_hours
FROM
    time_intervals t
GROUP BY
    t.deal_id;
```

is a complicated, but detailed approach, if you want to bring it in the query that you already gave along with this question, then it is something like -

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT deal_id,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM created_at::timestamp) IN (6, 7) THEN 0 ELSE extract(epoch from (lead(created_at) over (partition by deal_id order by created_at)) - created_at) / 3600 END), 0) AS time_for_deal
FROM table_1
GROUP BY deal_id;
```